# How to make my ASP.NET Web Api only take XML but also return JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json

For specific reasons I have to build an API that only takes XML content via POST. For this there are lots of posts out there - just remove the JsonFormatter from the GlobalConfiguration. But the API must be able to return JSON data when queried using GET. Is there a way that my method only accepts `Content-Type application/xml`? Maybe an attribute like HttpPost or something similar?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I just have an ApiController with a method flagged with the HttpPost attribute (and a binding model). This binding model should be only accepted via XML not via JSON. 

Example:
`[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult POST(int id, BindingModel model)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can validate them before perform the actual logic by checking ContentType as below:

```
if (Request.Content != null) {
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType.StartsWith(MediaType.Xml)) {
        //Perform your Logic here
    }
    /*
    //you can skip below  MediaType.Json  block 
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType.StartsWith(MediaType.Json)) {
    }
    */
}
```